# Py3k MySQL driver for SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to find MySQL driver written in Python 3 which I may bind to SQL Alchemy. So it should be compatiable with DB-API 2.

The only driver which can connect to MySQL db in [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mypysql/). But I cannot bind it with SQL Alchemy.

So, are there any other drivers which I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oursql is [compatible with Python3](http://packages.python.org/oursql/) and [may bind to SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/news.html#3). It is not written in Python3, but then, neither is mypysql.